# Asignar diferentes valores a un array con un switch

Tags: java

Quiero asignar a un array diferentes valores usando un switch, por ejemplo si la variable level es 1 entonces el array tendrá los valores

```
//Codigo de ejemplo
char[] testArray = null;
testArray = {1, 2, 3};
```

Si level tiene valor 2 entonces

```
//Codigo de ejemplo
testArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

Etcetera...

Para el programa real usa letras japonesas, el problema que tengo es que NetBeans muestra el error

```
Not a statement
';' expected
```

He probado muchas formas pero no logro dar con una sola solución

Todas las variables con la información son de clase

```
private static final char A = '\u3042';
    private static final char I = '\u3044';
    private static final char U = '\u3046';
    private static final char E = '\u3048';
    private static final char O = '\u304A';

    private static final char KA = '\u304B';
    private static final char KI = '\u304D';
    private static final char KU = '\u304F';
    private static final char KE = '\u3051';
    private static final char KO = '\u3053';

    private static final char SA = '\u3055';
    private static final char SHI = '\u3057';
    private static final char SU = '\u3059';
    private static final char SE = '\u305B';
    private static final char SO = '\u305D';

    private static final char TA = '\u305F';
    private static final char CHI = '\u3061';
    private static final char TSU = '\u3063';
    private static final char TE = '\u3066';
    private static final char TO = '\u3068';

    private static final char NA = '\u306A';
    private static final char NI = '\u306B';
    private static final char NU = '\u306C';
    private static final char NE = '\u306D';
    private static final char NO = '\u306E';

    private static final char HA = '\u306F';
    private static final char HI = '\u3072';
    private static final char FU = '\u3075';
    private static final char HE = '\u3078';
    private static final char HO = '\u307B';

    private static final char MA = '\u307E';
    private static final char MI = '\u307F';
    private static final char MU = '\u3080';
    private static final char ME = '\u3081';
    private static final char MO = '\u3082';

    private static final char RA = '\u3089';
    private static final char RI = '\u308A';
    private static final char RU = '\u308B';
    private static final char RE = '\u308C';
    private static final char RO = '\u308D';

    private static final char YA = '\u3084';
    private static final char YU = '\u3086';
    private static final char YO = '\u3088';

    private static final char WA = '\u308F';
    private static final char WO = '\u3092';
    private static final char N = '\u3093';

    /**
     *
     */
    public static char[] KATAKANA = null;

    public static final String[] ROMANJI = {
        "a", "i", "u", "e", "o",
        "ka", "ki", "ku", "ke", "ko",
        "sa", "shi", "su", "se", "so",
        "ta", "chi", "tsu", "te", "to",
        "na", "ni", "nu", "ne", "no",
        "ha", "hi", "fu", "he", "ho",
        "ma", "mi", "mu", "me", "mo",
        "ra", "ri", "ru", "re", "ro",
        "ya", "yu", "yo",
        "wa", "wo", "n"
    };
```

Metodo que cambia el valor del array (lo que estoy intentando y no consigo)

```
private static void chooseLevel(int level) {
        /**
         * Los niveles muestran los nuevos valores que va a tener el array, asi el nivel 1 tendra {a, i, u, e, o}
         * 
         * El nivel 2 tendra {a, i, u, e, o, ka, ki, ku, ke, ko}
         * 
         * Etc.
         * 
         * Nivel 1: a,i,u,e,o
         *
         * Nivel 2: ka,ki,ku,ke,ko
         *
         * Nivel 3: sa,shi,su,se,so
         *
         * Nivel 4: ta,chi,tsu,te,to
         *
         * Nivel 5: na,ni,nu,ne,no
         *
         * Nivel 6: ha,hi,fu,he,ho
         *
         * Nivel 7: ma,mi,mu,me,mo
         *
         * Nivel 8: ra,ri,ru,re,ro
         *
         * Nivel 9: ya,yu,yo
         *
         * Nivel 10: wa,wo,n
         */
        switch (level) {
            case 1:
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            case 6:
                break;
            case 7:
                break;
            case 8:
                break;
            case 9:
                break;
            case 10:
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Error de nivel");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Aunque en el método de arriba en el comentario ejemplo los contenidos estén en miníscula hace referencia a las variables de clase con el mismo nombre
Gracias de antemano

Comment: He intentado declarando el array en el propio metodo y demás pero tampoco funcionaba, además necesito que sea variable de clase asi que aunque hubiera funcionado no me habría valido como solucion

Comment: Por lo que veo te hace falta un punto y coma aquí: `testArray = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, el mismo error te dice que esperaba un punto y coma

Comment: testArray es solo para que veais lo que quiero hacer, en el codigo real que es el de abajo si que aparece el ;
Perdon por la confusion

Comment: @EduardoJiménez de hecho esa no es la manera de declarar un array de manera inline.

Comment: No? Y como es???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma en la que lo he resuelto es usando ArrayList para poder ampliar el Array que necesito.
He creado un Array con todos los caracteres y un ArrayList vacio que es el que voy a modificar

```
public Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public String[] listaCompleta = {A, I, U, E, O, KA, KI, KU, KE, KO ... };
public ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();

public class() {
  int nivel = sc.nextInt();
  switch(nivel) {
    case 1:
      ampliarLista(5);
      break;
    case 2:
      ampliarLista(10);
      break;
    ...

    case 10:
      ampliarLista(46);
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Error");
  }
}
```

La funcion que controla el aumento de los array dependiendo del nivel se llama ampliarLista()

```
public ArrayList ampliarLista(int n) {
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    lista.add(listaCompleta[i]);
  }
}
```

La unica razón por la que aampliarLista sea una funcion en vez de ponerlo en main es porque ya que hay 10 casos ahorro muchas lineas y queda más limpio el codigo

Answer (score 0):

Si lo he entendido bien, el problema es al asignar los valores que quieres al array en cada *case* del *switch*. En ese caso, se haría así:

```
case 1:
    KATAKANA = new char[] {A, I, U, E, O};
    break;
case 2:
    KATAKANA = new char[] {KA, KI, KU, KE, KO};
    break;
...
```

La forma `KATAKANA = {A, I, U, E, O}` sólo sirve para cuando estás declarando el propio array, es decir, `char[] KATAKANA = {A, I, U, E, O}`

Comment: Si y no... lo que quiero al reasignar el valor del Array es aumentarlo de tamaño, que en el caso 1 sea {A, I, U, E, O} pero en el caso 2 sea {A, I, U, E, O, KA, KI, KU, KE, KO}, y asi con todos los demas casos. El problema claro es que no se puede ampliar tamaño a un array directamente, por eso no se hacerlo